# How do I get cifs mounts to not have all the files owned by root?

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have researched this problem and found advise to use the uid argument, but it is not helping.

/etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.0.234/Backups /home/mark/Backups cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=mark gid=mark
//192.168.0.234/Documents /home/mark/NetDocuments cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=mark gid=mark
//192.168.0.234/Downloads /home/mark/NewDownloads cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=mark gid=mark
//192.168.0.234/Media /home/mark/Media cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=mark gid=mark
//192.168.0.234/Public /home/mark/Public cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=mark gid=mark
```

Revised fstab after first suggestion

```
//192.168.0.234/Backups /home/mark/Backups cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=1000 gid=1000
//192.168.0.234/Documents /home/mark/NetDocuments cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=1000 gid=1000
//192.168.0.234/Downloads /home/mark/NewDownloads cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=1000 gid=1000
//192.168.0.234/Media /home/mark/Media cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=1000 gid=1000
//192.168.0.234/Public /home/mark/Public cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=1000 gid=1000
```

```
mark@mark-Desktop:~/Media$ id -u;id -g
1000
1000
```

My username is "mark" and my group name is "mark"

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark mark   3812 Nov  6 17:58 .bashrc
```

I am running a fully patched Kubuntu 22.04 instance

```
mark@mark-Desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

All files in the smb mount are owned by root:

```
mark@mark-Desktop:~$ cd Media
mark@mark-Desktop:~/Media$ l
total 12216
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       0 Sep 13 10:00  ./
drwxr-x--- 35 mark mark    4096 Nov 20 18:17  ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       0 Nov  9 18:12  Astro/
```

Looking at the boot sequence I am getting parse errors trying to mount the drives:

```
Nov 20 19:01:27 mark-Desktop systemd-remount-fs[442]: mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 17 -- ignored
Nov 20 19:01:27 mark-Desktop systemd-remount-fs[442]: mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 18 -- ignored
Nov 20 19:01:27 mark-Desktop systemd-remount-fs[442]: mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 19 -- ignored
Nov 20 19:01:27 mark-Desktop systemd-remount-fs[442]: mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 20 -- ignored
Nov 20 19:01:27 mark-Desktop systemd-remount-fs[442]: mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 21 -- ignored
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your posted `fstab` had typos in it your syntax is incorrect.

This:

```
//192.168.0.234/Backups /home/mark/Backups cifs
vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials uid=mark gid=mark
```

Should be this:

```
//192.168.0.234/Backups /home/mark/Backups cifs
vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbCredentials,uid=mark,gid=mark
```

Commas ("`,`") should separate the options list in an `/etc/fstab` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your user name is 'mark', but your UID is a number (`id -u`).

Your group name is 'mark', but your GID is a number (`id -g`).

Replace the user name and group name with the numbers in your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Sadly, that did not work. Made the change, rebooted, same situation.

Comment: [Edit] your Question, show the revised `fstab`. Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Believe @Mobius1 's answer